# Selenium - select an element in a table after another element

Tags: html, selenium

In a table in a webpage there are several plain text elements (filenames) on the left and several hyperlinks to PDFs of the files:

```
Red report     Download PDF
Blue report    Download PDF
Green report   Download PDF
```

There are several such pages, and the files aren't always in the same order.

```
Red report     Download PDF
Green report   Download PDF
Blue report    Download PDF
```

etc.

I only ever need the pdf for `Green report`. Finding the text `Green report` in the page using find_element is easy. What I don't know how to do is to focus the driver on the link to the right of the text. The xpath doesn't work, because it varies from page to page, and unfortunately the title of the pdf in the href doesn't have "green report" or anything like that in it—it's just a bunch of numbers.

However, the link element always follows the filename element in the html. What I need to do is tell selenium: "find the text `Green report` and then click on the first link appearing in the html after that text."

I've looked high and low and don't even know how to go about doing this, so I can't offer code snippets of what I've tried.

Here's an actual example:

```
<tr id="detailMainForm:j_idt922:0" class="rf-dt-r rf-dt-fst-r oddRow"><td id="detailMainForm:j_idt922:0:j_idt924" class="rf-dt-c" style="width:10%;">09.07.2015</td><td id="detailMainForm:j_idt922:0:j_idt927" class="rf-dt-c" style="width:50%;">Translation of the ISR</td><td id="detailMainForm:j_idt922:0:j_idt930" class="rf-dt-c" style="width:15%;"><a href="/search/docservicepdf_pct/id00000029896067/ETISR/WO2015102081.pdf">PDF (1p.)</a></td><td id="detailMainForm:j_idt922:0:j_idt935" class="rf-dt-c" style="width:25%;"><a href="/search/docservicepdf_pct/id00000029896067/ETISR/WO2015102081.pdf?download">PDF (1p.)</a>, <a href="/search/docservicepct_file/WOid00000029896067/ETISR/WO2015102081.zip">ZIP(XML + TIFFs)</a></td></tr>
```

`Translation of the ISR` is the text corresponding to "Green report" in my example above.

The first instance (there happen to be two--sometimes there are more) of `PDF (1p.)` corresponds to "Download PDF."

Comment: Are you by any chance looking for 'following-sibling' ?? Im bit confused by you question.  if element with 'Green report' text is sibling of link u want to click, 'following-sibling' would the trick for you. ex:- //*[text()='Green report']/following-sibling::input

Comment: Could you please provide the html code of the both examples?

Comment: @Dileep17, Sibling! I didn't know that existed. I'll take a look at it.

Comment: @Eugene, I'll add an example to the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This XPath returns the link element having a `.pdf` href for the row containing the text "Translation of the ISR" :

```
//tr[td='Translation of the ISR']//a[contains(@href, '.pdf')]
```